Adding (search-result) marks to Firefox scrollbar (CSS?)
In Firefox, if you do a search (find-in-page), the browser will add lines to the scrollbar for each search-result found to make it easier to see how many search-results there are and where in the page they are located, as seen in the screenshot.
Is this only part of the browser, or is it achievable by a webpage (CSS/JavaScript)? All I can find is information about generic customization of size and shape of the scrollbar, not about marks in the scrollbar.


The feature you're describing is the default browser-based UI. It can be re-created in HTML/CSS/JS though, but you would need a method of finding the matches in the content of the DOM, determining their vertical position, then building the track bar to show their positions within the total document height. It's a straightforward process, but there is a LOT of steps to achieve it. Note that this will appear separately to the browser implementation, not as an integrated part of it

default browser-based UI you mean it's the browser-chrome, not the page? Firefox exposes pretty much everything for customization, there's nothing for this, like through the shadow-dom or something, not even via about:config options?

default browser-based UI you mean it's the browser-chrome Correct. I tend not to use the word 'chrome' when talking about the UI of the browser to save confusion :) What I can guarantee though is that the document outline shown when searching won't be part of the DOM. I haven't looked in to about:config, but I highly doubt there's anything configurable about it in there

Could you explain a bit more what you are wanting to achieve - what is your use case and context?

@RoryMcCrossan fair enough, Google really stole that term.  It's a shame this isn't exposed because it's very useful. I found a Reddit thread where someone asked about it and people said you'd have to write it yourself which is apparently a lot of work.  Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it (not all questions get the desired result ).

@AHaworth, I'm trying to find out if there's any way to put lines in the scrollbar the way that Firefox (and ostensibly also Chrome and some text-editors) do. I've got a userscript that extends the functionality on a website and one of the features I added was a search-function. I highlight the matching results in the page, but would like to show them in the scrollbar as well, like the find-in-page function does.
